# Convert a date column to higher resolution in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` of which one column is `time`:

```
    time    
0   2014-01-01
1   2014-01-02
2   2014-01-03
3   2014-01-04
4   2014-01-05
     ...    ...
```

I'd like to convert the dates to `datetime` with granularity up to seconds, for instance, from `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-01 11:00:00`. What is the best way to do it?

---

I tried the following methods:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

and this:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

then this:

```
df['time'] = [time.date() for time in df['time']]
```

Strangely, nothing happens for all these methods.

Comment: what type is the data currently? string?

Comment: @DerekEden `df` is `dataframe`; `df['time']` is `series`.

Comment: @nilsinelabore: you should have input in the same format as well. for example, if the input data is `2014-01-01 01:01:01`, then you can convert it using `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"` in the pd.to_datetime() function.

Comment: Hi @vb_rises how can I make it the same format then?

Comment: you don't have the correct data. how you added `11:00:00` into the date? What's the logic there?

Comment: series of objects of what data type? @nilsinelabore

Comment: do you want all the hours to be `11:00:00`? if so try `df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime) + pd.DateOffset(hour=11,minute=0,second=0)`

Comment: @DerekEden yeah it's a string..

Comment: @vb_rises I would like to add time to the `datetime` data for later manipulation.

Comment: @Datanovice Can't `df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)` be simplified to `df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` ?

Comment: it can indeed, why don't you post that as an answer @AMC  I was being lazy and typing apply, been using SQL alot lately and most of my methods are within brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misled a bit by what you see.
Pandas makes a floor on timestamps, if we are `00:00:00` at the given day.

So when you make a

```
 df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

then the conversion from string to time is being made and this is in `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` format, but the data after the days will be displayed only if they are not `00:00:00`.
A bit example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['2014/04/28 00:00:00', '2014-04-29', '2014-04-30'], columns=['time'])
print(df)
print(type(df['time'][0]))
```

**OUT:**

```
                  time
0  2014/04/28 00:00:00
1           2014-04-29
2           2014-04-30
<class 'str'>
```

Conversion with `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
print(df)
print(type(df['time'][0]))
```

**OUT:**

```
        time
0 2014-04-28
1 2014-04-29
2 2014-04-30
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

print(df['time'][0])
```

Take one element of Series:

**OUT:**

```
2014-04-28 00:00:00
```

Now the same, if one of our timestamps is not at `00:00:00`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2014/04/28 10:00:00', '2014-04-29', '2014-04-30'], columns=['time'])
print(df)
print(type(df['time'][0]))
```

**OUT:**

```
                  time
0  2014/04/28 10:00:00
1           2014-04-29
2           2014-04-30
<class 'str'>
```

Conversion with `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
print(df)
print(type(df['time'][0]))
```

**OUT:**

```
                 time
0 2014-04-28 10:00:00
1 2014-04-29 00:00:00
2 2014-04-30 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```